# getting an error since 1.8.2 update

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm getting an error when trying to index with search API since I upgraded to 1.8.2 dev server... Here's Traceback with relevant data:

```
search.Index( 'something' ).put( self.document() )

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\api\search\search.py", line 2485, in put
  response)

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
  return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
  rpc.CheckSuccess()

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
  self.request, self.response)

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
  self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)

File "C:\Dev\GAE\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
  raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'AddFieldType'
```

Anyone knows why is this happening? Worked on 1.8.1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove your search index and reindex your entities.
that solved it for me.

Comment: I tried deleting documents from index, but that didn't help. I'm getting another error when trying to do `delete_schema`... How did you remove index? Any special dev-server commands? Thanks.

Comment: how do you start your SDK? do you specify a path for the search index file?

Comment: include '--clear_search_indexes=yes' in the command you use to start the server.

Comment: BTW, @Greg, where did you find that command? It's not in the official list: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: If you run the server with --help you'll get all of the options